# In moment js, is it possible to display the days remaing until it reaches a certain point of time?

Tags: javascript, momentjs

In my case, I want to display how long an employee has been working with the company based on his entry date each day starting when he reaches 5 months and 1 day until 6 months.

Here is my code:

```
var remark = "";         
                var dateofentry = moment(new Date(parseInt(item.DateOfEntry.substr(6)))).format('MMM D, YYYY');
                var dateofentry6mos = moment(dateofentry).add(6, 'months').format('MMM D, YYYY');
                var dateofentry12mos = moment(dateofentry).add(1, 'year').format('MMM D, YYYY');
                var CurrentDate = moment().format('MMM D, YYYY');




                for (var m = moment(CurrentDate) ; m.isBefore(dateofentry6mos) ; m.add(1, 'days'))


                {                    
                    remark = ("<td style='text-align:left;'>" + "Reached <span style='color:#014da2;font-weight:bold;'>" + m.format('M') + "</span>" + " months and " + m.format('D') + " days today " + "</td>");
                }
```

But it is displaying the following which is wrong

[click here to see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2DBj.jpg)

Comment: What exactly do you think is going wrong here? What _specifically_ are you trying to do, and where are you not seeing what you expected?

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Comment: Its not clear what you're doing, but you can get difference between two dates using `.diff()`